# Is it possible to install a Safari extension on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, safari-extensions

Is it possible to install a Safari extension on an iPhone, if so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Safari on iOS does not support general extensions added to the web browser. Apps on iOS *can* provide [app extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html) such as [action extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1) and [share extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1) which are supported on iOS, or [content blockers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ContentBlocker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH26-SW1), but these frameworks are limited in what access the extension has.

Comment: ok, thank you. do you know if it's possible to [inject a script](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html) with a content blocking app or can they only remove content?

Comment: @2083 It's not possible to inject anything into the page, that's one of the main major restrictions on iOS. This is possible with jailbreaking though.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 12 you can run JavaScript on website through siri shortcuts share extension.

Comment: How does this answer the question?